# MLE vs. Optimization in R to find best performer

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, maximum-likelihood, optimization

I have data that looks like this:

```
machine = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",6),rep("C",7))
score1 = c(.0,.2,.34,.69,.50,.50,.23,.63,.69,.98,.39,.40,.45,.45,.46,.48,.69,.99,.66,.63,.16,.16,.55)
score2 = c(.58,.78,.39,.25,.36,.4,.3,.10,.36,.15,.4,.49,.15,.14,.36,.98,.98,.40,.12,.12,.33,.1,.1)
weightedscore = .5*score1 +.5*score2
d =data.frame(machine = machine , score1 = score1, score2 =score2, weightedscore = weightedscore )
d
avg_score1 = aggregate(d$score1, by=list(d$machine), FUN=mean) 
avg_score2 = aggregate(d$score2, by=list(d$machine), FUN=mean)[2]
avg_weightedscore = aggregate(d$weightedscore, by=list(d$machine), FUN=mean)[2]
averages =cbind(avg_score1, avg_score2, avg_weightedscore)
colnames(averages) <- c("machine","Avg_Score1","Avg_Score2","Avg_WeightedScore")
averages
```

I want to score all 23 observations across all 3 machines by combining score1 and score2 because my goal is to rank the machines by who is best at maximizing score1 and score2.  Initially my score has a 50/50 weighting:    weightedscore = .5*score1 +.5*score2   But I'd like to find the optimal weights that maximize both score 1 and score 2.

How would that be done or is there a better way to rank the machines based on who is best at maximizing score1 and score2?

Thank you.